# Meteor : Passing route parameter to template

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I have the following route :

```
  this.route('create', {path: '/create/:promocode'});
```

Is it possible, somehow, to directly access `promocode` from my template, without having to define a dedicated helper for it?

Comment: You mean in html? No.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I know I can call `Router.current()` from JS. 
Many thanks for your answer!

Comment: Also I'd highly suggest you look at the [iron router guide](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/).  The recommended syntax is to have the path as the first parameter to .route, and name the path by passing a 'name' field in the options object.

Comment: However, you could just add `data: function(){ return this.params.promocode; }` to your route and then `{{this}}` in your html would evaluate to the `promocode` param in the url. Technically that doesn't involve a helper. Perhaps this is sufficient?

Comment: For me this is the same this. I was trying to avoid having to declare a function for it. But if I need to, then I prefer to declare a `helper`, which will be names `promocode`, as it is more explicite. 

Thank you very much for this alternative though